# Do Lagrange-like points exist on elliptical orbits?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, three-body-problem

I noticed that

1. [Lagrange points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point) exist on a circle with radius of the orbit radius about the moon.
2. Changing the radius of the circle to the chord length of an ellipse results in a point at the intersection of the elliptical orbit and circle radius chord length at which point there is a quasi-periodic Lagrange-like point.
3. There are numerous recent papers that mention quasi-periodic Trojan asteroid orbits at Lagrange-like points. These papers do not have a good simple explanation like 2 does.
4. An examination of the three-body problem could use this to explain the previous instability.

Comment: It is unclear what exact answer OP is looking for. Without doing any analysis, we already know that we recover the 5 [Lagrange points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) in the limit of vanishing [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity) $e\to 0$. So for sufficiently small eccentricity $e\ll 1$, there must be an approximate/effective notion of Lagrange points, computable by numerical methods. On the other hand, exact analytical closed-form expressions are unlikely to exist.

Comment: Unless the lagrange points are a function of a standing gravitational wave, then then ellipsoidal derivatives should be analytical based on keplers law of conserved gravitational standing wave.  The 60 degree lagrange triangles indicate a conserved standing circular gravitational wave.